# Hints to prove $2^{(p−1)/2}$ is congruent to 1 (mod p) or p-1 (mod p)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cryptography

I'm working on this problem:

Compute the value of
    $2^{(p−1)/2}$ (mod p)
for every prime 3 ≤ p < 20. Make a conjecture as to the possible values of $2^{(p−1)/2}$ (mod p) when p is prime and prove that your conjecture is correct.

I've computed the values for 3 ≤ p < 20

`3  => 2 (mod p)
5  => 4 (mod p)
7  => 1 (mod p)
11 => 10 (mod p)
13 => 12 (mod p)
17 => 1 (mod p)
19 => 18 (mod p)`

My conjecture: the result is either `1 (mod p)` or `p-1 (mod p)`

I've having trouble figuring out how to prove my conjecture. The given equation is also very similar to Fermat's Little Theorem. I haven't yet figured out how I can simplfy/rewrite this equation to apply Fremat's Little Theorem, or how adding the `/2` effects his theorem.

I'm not looking for a direct answer or anything, but some hints if I am on the right track, and if my conjecture is going in the right direction or way off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=2^{(p-1)/2}$. Then $a^2=2^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$,
by Fermat's little theorem. Can you prove that $a^2\equiv1\pmod p$
implies that $a\equiv\pm1\pmod p$?

Comment: Thank you! I was significantly over complicating this in my head. It amazing how simple it actually was.